# Order Comment Just before Place order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders

Is Default Magento 2 provide an order comment option just before placing the order?

If not someone suggests me a good plugin or any custom method to do.

Comment: I can recommend https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments (open source)

Comment: definitely recommend this plugin - https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-delivery-instructions-and-date.html

Comment: Free Extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-comment.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Magento default doesn't provide that function. If you only want give customer ability comment before placing order, try this [Magento 2 Order Comment on Place Order](https://rohitkundale.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/magento-2-order-comment-on-place-order/)

If you want more custom field on checkout page, try this
https://amasty.com/order-attributes-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento not providing order comment feature, but you can use an extension for the same which is free.

[Order Comment For Magento 2](https://evincemage.com/order-comment-magento2.html)

Comment: The extension is not free anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free extension.

https://github.com/bikashkaushik/magento2-OrderComment

Comment: Still free, thank you!