# How to display order comment on checkout page?

Tags: magento2

I want to display the order comment textarea on checkout page. I can't find any setting in configuration to enable this feature. Any idea? Im using default magento 2 theme Luma

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139546/order-comment-just-before-place-order-magento-2

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-comment-magento-2-checkout-shipping-address-fields/ kindly refer to this answer this will help you then you can get this by using plugin of save order

Comment: W1ZARD, donot put link as full answer. Answer should have some content